# Difference between document.createElement('script') vs jQuery .getScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, getscript, script-tag

I've been having an issue getting `.getScript` to work in some odd cases.

For instance, this works to load the scripts only when needed.

```
function twitterSDK() {
    $jQ.getScript('http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js');
}

function diggShare() {
    $jQ.getScript('http://widgets.digg.com/buttons.js');
}

function buzzShare() {
    $jQ.getScript('http://www.google.com/buzz/api/button.js');
}
```

However it doesn't seem to work on a few scripts that I wrote. If I call `.getScript` to fetch this JS file I've uploaded to Pastebin ( http://pastebin.com/GVFcMJ4P ) and call `tweetStream();` nothing happens. However, if I do the following it works:

```
var twitter = document.createElement('script');
twitter.type = 'text/javascript';
twitter.async = true;
twitter.src = '/path-to/tweet.js';
$jQ('.twitter-section').append(twitter);
tweetStream();
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be awesome, thanks!

P.S. Which method is faster or more efficient?

**Note: My code isn't hosted on pastebin, I just uploaded the contents of the .js file that is on my server to that site so it is easy to share. I am not leeching of pastebin for hosting ;)**

Comment: When you put `/path-to/tweet.js` is that a file in your own server? Or the url from pastebin? And when you call $.getScript do you give it the same url?

Comment: Both scripts are a `.js` file on my server. I'm not loading anything from pastebin. :) It works when using the `createElement` method, but it doesn't work if I do `$jQ.getScript('/path-to/tweet.js');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery's `$jQ.getScript()` is an asynchronous call. So if you were calling `tweetStream()` immediately after the `getScript()`, it would run before the script arrived.

You can call `tweetStream()` from (or as) a callback instead.

```
$jQ.getScript('/path-to/tweet.js', function() {
    tweetStream();
});
```

or this if you don't care about the value of `this` in `tweetStream()`.

```
$jQ.getScript('/path-to/tweet.js', tweetStream);
```

Comment: You nailed it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey noticed one issue, your code works perfectly in the latest stable releases of Chrome, IE, Opera, and Safari. However your method isn't working in Firefox 3.6. It probably once every 10 refreshes or so. The `createElement` method did however work in all browsers. P.S. I properly referenced `this` to solve any issues relating to that. Here's the updated code: http://pastebin.com/wnP88v7z I noted which script is which with comments.

Comment: @Sahas: Could be a jQuery bug. The [bug tracker](http://bugs.jquery.com/) isn't loading for me right now, but it may be worth searching for that issue to see if it is known. When you say it doesn't work, do you meant the callback function doesn't fire at all? If you do an `alert()`, does it fire?

Comment: So here's the odd thing. If the first statement in `tweetStream()` function in the `tweet.js` file is a `alert()` it works in all browsers, but Firefox. (Even IE works... really!) So to try something different, I decided to call the `tweetStream()` function from within the `tweet.js` file and it began to work perfectly. No clue why it was being problematic before!

Comment: @Sahas: Seems like the callback function to `getScript()` is either being called too early, or not being called at all. I'd still be curious to know what happens if you place an `alert()` directly in the callback. As in: `function(){alert('test');tweetStream();}`

Comment: ...also, I'd be curious to know what version of jQuery you're using.